# Does $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \cos^8(n)}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find if the series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \cos^8(n)}$$ converges or diverges. I have tried multiple online calculators, but none seem to work (even WolframAlpha, or Symbolab).

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that
$$\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{n\cos^8(n)}.$$

Comment: Comparison test could perhaps be used

Comment: $\sum \dfrac{\cos^8(n)}{n}$ would be interesting.

Comment: @MariusS.L. It would diverge since
$$\cos^8(n)=\frac{1}{128}(56\cos(2n)+28\cos(4n)+8\cos(6n)+\cos(8n)+35),$$
and the sums $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(kn)}{n}$ converge due to Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 4):

$$n\geq n\cos^8(n) \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n\cos^8(n)}$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n}$$ diverges therefore the sum diverge.